# Can I assign the python interpreter for linux based Pycharm via the command line during or after install?

Tags: linux, pycharm

I'm building a docker container with Pycharm installed and would like to Pycharm to know where the python interpreter is without having to manually set it when opening up Pycharm.

Comment: It is possible but will require a lot of manual work, you need to 1) edit xml in `<project>/.idea/` to specify which interpreter is used 2) add the interpreter in `~/.PyCharm<VERSION>/config/options/jdk.table.xml`. See the discussion in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34864

Comment: how do you use PyCharm in container? PyCharm is able to auto-configure interpreter, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40336